# SVG tag HTML auto filter when add Description box in Category

Tags: html, wordpress, svg

I was try build one landing page with Generate Block. That URL: domain.com/landingpage
And after that I copy all HTML in body to paste into Description of Category because I need use that landing page in category, so that url: domain.com/landingpage

And I was copy CSS of Generate Block. I very need build landing page with category.
I think it useful but have one problem that is SVG tag in HTML was remove all when I click save. Have any problem with that? Can you give me about that information?

This is location in category I was paste HTML code: https://ibb.co/4FDmTVM
But when I add code HTML in to that. It auto remove all code like this:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 60 4.688" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M57.656 0H2.344a2.343 2.343 0 100 4.688h55.312a2.344 2.344 0 000-4.688z"></path></svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

The TinyMCE is preventing you from adding SVG items. Add the code below to you functions.php to allow svg elements:

```
function allow_svg_tinymce_elements( $mceInit  ) {

    $extended_valid_elements = "svg[*],defs[*],pattern[*],desc[*],metadata[*],g[*],mask[*],path[*],line[*],marker[*],rect[*],circle[*],ellipse[*],polygon[*],polyline[*],linearGradient[*],radialGradient[*],stop[*],image[*],view[*],text[*],textPath[*],title[*],tspan[*],glyph[*],symbol[*],switch[*],use[*]";

    $mceInit['extended_valid_elements'] .= ',' . $extended_valid_elements;
    
    return $mceInit;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'allow_svg_tinymce_elements');
```

Comment: Thanks you so much. I was release problem. But can you help me about different? I see TinyMCE was auto add class <p> before <a>. Have have way to remove auto add <p> class before <a>? Because that is a buttom. Not content so I don't need it auto have. Have any way?